# Flutter rebuild widget with File changed possible?

Tags: file, flutter, setstate

I have a small Thumbnail widget that takes a File and displays it:

```
class ThumbnailViewer extends StatelessWidget {

  ThumbnailViewer({this.key, this.image}) : super(key: key);
  Key key;
  File image;
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return getThumbnail();
  }
  
  Widget getThumbnail() {
    return ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        child: Center(
          child: Image.file(
            image,
            fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
            width: double.infinity,
            filterQuality: FilterQuality.none,
          ),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

This widget is first created like this:

```
return ThumbnailViewer(image: File(FileHelper.getPhotoPath(shroom.photo, shroom.id)));
```

Then the file that is referenced by that path is changed and setState is called. However the new image is not displayed.

Does flutter not notice file changes when rebuilding? Is there any way to listen to file changes?
Thanks

Comment: where do you call setState?

Comment: The actual scenario where i'm doing this is more complex.
Inside a showModalBottomSheet builder, i push to a new screen that changes the images, once that screen pops i call my "modalSetState" like this:

showModalBottomSheet(
builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, modalSetState) {
          <push here> . then({
          modalSetState((){});
})

Comment: where the 'ThumbnailViewer' is implemented ?

Comment: The thumbnail widget is used inside the statefulBuilder in the modal